# Can't import class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I simply can't seem to import classes in Javascript anymore.

My App.js: 
[image]

My User.js (None of the classes import, but the statement to import this class comes first as you will see in the error) :
[image]

The error message:
[image]

I know that:
 - the paths to the classes are right
 - the names of the classes are right and that the IDE recognizes them (the IDE suggests what values need 
   to be in the constructor)
 - This way of importing / exporting the class should be right

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a Java question

Comment: 1. Please post text, not images of text. 2. Please don't spam language tags.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have a code that was intended for the browser however you're running it with Node.js which 1. doesn't support `import` and `export` keywords in .js files; 2. doesn't have `document.*` APIs.

To make this code work in the browser, it's still recommended to compile it to ES5 code using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) first.

Comment: I'm aware that this is meant for the browser.  It doesn't matter whether I run that code in the browser or not to show the Syntaxerror occuring though..

Anyways, the browser shows the same error. Adding "type='module'" to the script tag doesn't work.